# invoke {{> loginButtons }} functionality from backend in Meteor

Tags: meteor, twitter, meteor-accounts

My application interacts with user through Direct Message in twitter.
I have have to then perform some twitter operations on behalf of my twitter user for that I need user to authenticate my application which can be achieved by adding

```
accounts-twitter
```

but I don't have front-end like

```
{{> loginButtons}}
```

since my interaction happens through Direct Messages,
to achieve this I have to forcefully re-direct user to twitter authentication page in pop-up (based on some input of-course)
how do I invoke this functionality in back-end

Answer (score 0):

Your "user" object, when loaded on the server, should contain an access token that you can call against Twitter's RESTful API. You can also see this token by viewing your app's DB (`meteor mongo`) directly.

Next step is to create a server-side method to do whatever you need your application to do with the current user's access, and call it from the browser.

Comment: But how exactly invoke the above action in the first place which will redirect user to twitter for authentication(function that loginButtons perform)

Comment: Best to refer to the source code here :) https://github.com/meteor/accounts/blob/master/packages/twitter/twitter_client.js